# How to implement a recv() callback

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock2

I'm trying to improve my knowledge of OOP and decided to create a simple class to simplify sockets programming.
This is a learning experiment so I do not want to use boost, or other libraries.

I want to implement an *event-driven* recv(). Meaning, everytime there is new data coming in, it should call my function.

I think I need to create a thread to run a recv() loop and then call my function everytime there is new data. Is there other way around using threads? I want my code to be portable.

Here is my simple Class and example code:

**class.h:**

```
#ifndef _SOCKETSCLASS_H
#define _SOCKETSCLASS_H

#if defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32) || defined(__WIN32) && !defined(__CYGWIN__)
    #define W32
    #include <WinSock2.h>
    #pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#else
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <arpa/inet.h>
    #include <netdb.h>

    #define SOCKET int
#endif
#include <string>
#include<ctime>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <varargs.h>
#include <tchar.h>

using namespace std;

#ifdef _DEBUG
    #define DEBUG(msg) XTrace(msg)
#else
    #define DEBUG(msg, params)
#endif

struct TCP_Client_opts
{
    BOOL    UseSCprotocol;
    BOOL    UseEncryption;
    BOOL    UseCompression;
    int     CompressionLevel;
    void    *Callback;
    BOOL    async;
};

struct TCP_Stats
{
    unsigned long int   upload; //bytes
    unsigned long int   download;//bytes
    time_t              uptime; //seconds
};

class TCP_Client
{
    public:
        TCP_Client();
        TCP_Client(TCP_Client_opts opts_set);
        ~TCP_Client();
        SOCKET          GetSocket();
        void            SetOptions(TCP_Client_opts opts_set);
        TCP_Client_opts GetOptions();
        BOOL            Connect(string server, int port);
        int             Send(string data);
        int             Recv(string *data);
        BOOL            IsConnected();
        int             Disconnect();
        TCP_Stats       GetStats();
    private:
        SOCKET          s = SOCKET_ERROR;
        TCP_Client_opts opts;
        TCP_Stats       stats;
        BOOL            connected = FALSE;
        time_t          starttime;
};
#endif
```

**class.cpp:**

```
#include "SocketsClass.h"

void XTrace(LPCTSTR lpszFormat, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, lpszFormat);
    int nBuf;
    TCHAR szBuffer[512]; // get rid of this hard-coded buffer
    nBuf = _vsnwprintf_s(szBuffer, 511, lpszFormat, args);
    ::OutputDebugString(szBuffer);
    va_end(args);
}


TCP_Client::TCP_Client(TCP_Client_opts opts_set)
{
    SetOptions(opts_set);
}

TCP_Client::~TCP_Client()
{
    Disconnect();
}

TCP_Client::TCP_Client()
{
}

void TCP_Client::SetOptions(TCP_Client_opts opts_set)
{
    opts = opts_set;
}

TCP_Client_opts TCP_Client::GetOptions()
{
    return opts;
}

SOCKET TCP_Client::GetSocket()
{
    return s;
}

BOOL TCP_Client::IsConnected()
{
    return connected;
}

int TCP_Client::Disconnect()
{
    connected = FALSE;
    stats.uptime = time(0) - starttime;
    return shutdown(s, 2);
}

BOOL TCP_Client::Connect(string server, int port)
{
    struct sockaddr_in RemoteHost;

#ifdef W32
    WSADATA       wsd;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsd) != 0)
    {
        DEBUG(L"Failed to load Winsock!\n");
        return FALSE;
    }
#endif

    //create socket if it is not already created
    if (s == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        //Create socket
        s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if (s == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            DEBUG(L"Could not create socket");
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    //setup address structure
    if (inet_addr(server.c_str()) == INADDR_NONE)
    {
        struct hostent *he;

        //resolve the hostname, its not an ip address
        if ((he = gethostbyname(server.c_str())) == NULL)
        {
            //gethostbyname failed
            DEBUG(L"gethostbyname() - Failed to resolve hostname\n");
            return FALSE;
        }
    }   
    else//plain ip address
    {
        RemoteHost.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(server.c_str());
    }

    RemoteHost.sin_family = AF_INET;
    RemoteHost.sin_port = htons(port);

    //Connect to remote server
    if (connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&RemoteHost, sizeof(RemoteHost)) < 0)
    {
        DEBUG(L"connect() failed");
        return FALSE;
    }

    connected = TRUE;
    starttime = time(0);
    stats.download = 0;
    stats.upload = 0;
    return TRUE;
}

TCP_Stats TCP_Client::GetStats()
{
    if (connected==TRUE)
        stats.uptime = time(0)-starttime;
    return stats;
}

int TCP_Client::Send(string data)
{
    stats.upload += data.length();
    return send(s, data.c_str(), data.length(), 0);

}

int TCP_Client::Recv(string *data)
{
    int ret = 0;
    char buffer[512];

    ret = recv(s, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    data->assign(buffer);
    data->resize(ret);
    stats.download += data->length();

    return ret;
}
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "SocketsClass.h"

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char *argv)
{
    TCP_Client tc;
    tc.Connect("127.0.0.1", 9999);
    tc.Send("HEllo");
    string data;
    tc.Recv(&data);
    puts(data.c_str());
    tc.Disconnect();
    printf("\n\nDL: %i\nUP: %i\nUptime: %u\n", tc.GetStats().download, tc.GetStats().upload, tc.GetStats().uptime);
    return 0;
}
```

Some extra questions:

1. Imagine I'm sending a file. How would my function know that the current data is related to the previous message?
2. How is my class design and implementation? SHould I change anything?

Thank you

Comment: You could take a look on [Boost ASIO](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) and see how they do it. But to sum it up: If you want to make it completely asynchronous then you need threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "portable" you mean runs on other platforms besides Windows then a `recv()` loop in a worker thread is your only portable option.  On Windows specifically, you have some additional choices:

1. Allocate a hidden window and then use `WSAAsyncSelect()` to receive `FD_READ` notifications.  This requires a message loop, which you can put in a worker thread.
2. Use `WSAEventSelect()` to register a waitable event for `FD_READ` notifications and then wait for those events via `WSAWaitForMultipleEvents()` in a thread.
3. use `WSARecv()` with an I/O Completion Port. Poll the IOCP via `GetQueuedCompletionResult()` in a thread.

As for your question regarding messaging, TCP is a byte stream, it has no concept of messages.  You have to frame your messages yourself.  You can either:

1. give each message a fixed header that contains the message length. Read the header first, then read however many bytes it says, then read the next header, and so on.
2. separate each message with a unique delimiter that does not appear in the message data.  Read until you encounter that delimiter, then read until the next delimiter, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Have your event loop call either [`poll`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/poll.html) or [`select`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/select.html) to determine if there is data that can be read on the socket(s). Then read it, and call the appropriate callback function.

Comment: If you are calling `recv()` in a dedicated thread, using `poll()` or `select()` is overkill when you can simply let `recv()` block until data arrives.

Comment: @RemyLebeau : that is only really an option if your event loop only has to deal with a single socket, and only with receiving data. A more general event loop might have to deal with outgoing traffic and/or more sockets, and maybe other things. That's the advantage of `select` and `poll` - they can deal with multiple sockets and multiple types of events on them.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker - the OP specifically asks about a TCP client - one socket.

Comment: @MartinJames : the OP was interested in creating a "class to simplify sockets programming" in an "event-driven" way. The single client code was example code. Even if only dealing with one socket, in event driven programming, an event loop is likely to deal with more than just `recv` events.